# Android Activity lifecycle: onStart called before onStop of previous activity

Tags: android

I am implementing some logic using ActivityLifecycleCallbacks to keep track of onStart/onStop.

My assumption was when user moves from Activity A to activity B, activityA's onStop is called first and then Activity B's onStart but when I instrument logging as below, it seems the behavioru is opposite (B's onStart is called first).

My question is - is this behaviour consistent for all devices and OS versions? I could not find any documentation about this behaviour. How about onResume/onPause?

```
app.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        Log.d("test", activity.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Start");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        Log.d("test", activity.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Stop");
    }
```

Comment: Here is some official documentation about the activity lifecycle
[Activity-lifecycle concepts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc),

Basically, onStop() method will call when your activity is no longer visible to the user.

Comment: sure but it won't tell you about onStop/onStart order across multiple activities?

Comment: I think that makes sense, consider you have transition animation when you go from `Activity` A to B, it's safe to trigger `onStop()` only when the `Activity` A is completely invisible, but at the same moment the `Acitivty` B has become completely visible. Therefore the order of: new `Activity` triggers `onStart()` then old `Activity` triggers `onStop()` is resonable.

Comment: @kazuki, Suppose you have 2 activity named Activity A & Activity B. When Activity A starts first 3 methods will call i.e: onCreate(),onStart(),onResume(). Now start Activity B, here first, it will call onPause() of Activity A then same 3 methods of activityLifeCycle will be called for Activity B then it will call onStop() of Activity A.

Comment: Ah ok it's documented in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#coordinating-activities